# problem with scrolling up or down of listview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

When I try to take all the values of the NumberPicker, it correctly returns the ones in the middle, while the first and last returns only the last one that has been modified between them. I don't understand where I'm wrong.

```js
public class piatto {
    String nome;
    String Descrizione;
    String prezzo;
    String immagine;
    String tag;


    public piatto(String nome, String Descrizione, String prezzo, String immagine, String tag) {
        this.nome= nome;
        this.Descrizione= Descrizione;
        this.prezzo= prezzo;
        this.immagine=immagine;
        this.tag=tag;

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return Descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        Descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public String getPrezzo() {
        return prezzo;
    }

    public void setPrezzo(String prezzo) {
        this.prezzo = prezzo;
    }

    public String getImmagine() {
        return immagine;
    }

    public void setImmagine(String immagine) {
        this.immagine = immagine;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

}
```

this is my adapeter

```js
public class ProductListAdapterforListView extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<piatto> mProductList;

    public ProductListAdapterforListView(Context mContext, List<piatto> mProductList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mProductList = mProductList;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mProductList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public piatto getItem(int position) {
        return mProductList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listitemview ;

        if (convertView==null){

            listitemview = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.row_data_list, null);


            ImageView i = (ImageView) listitemview.findViewById(R.id.imagepiatto);
            com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker numberPicker = (com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker) listitemview.findViewById(R.id.number_picker);
            TextView n=(TextView) listitemview.findViewById(R.id.namepiatto);
            TextView p=(TextView) listitemview.findViewById(R.id.prezzopiatto);

            n.setText(mProductList.get(position).getNome());
            p.setText(mProductList.get(position).getPrezzo()+" €");
            Picasso.get().load(mProductList.get(position).getImmagine()).into(i);
        } else {
            listitemview=convertView;
        }

        return listitemview;
    }
    
}
```

And this is my Java class where I get the values of the NumberPicker of each Item

```js
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId()==R.id.buttonnext){
        
            Float totale = (float) 0.0;
            String listapiatti="";

            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++) {
                view = listView.getChildAt(i);

                TextView n = view.findViewById(R.id.namepiatto);
                String nome = n.getText().toString();

                TextView p = view.findViewById(R.id.prezzopiatto);
                String pricestr = p.getText().toString();
                String[] prezzo = pricestr.split(" ");
                Float price = Float.valueOf(prezzo[0]);

                com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker numberPicker = (com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.number_picker);
                int value = numberPicker.getValue();

                if (value != 0) {
                    totale = totale + (price * value);
                    listapiatti = listapiatti + nome + ": " + value + ", ";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(i)+" "+value,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
            String finale=String.valueOf(totale);


            startActivity(new Intent(carrello3.this, ordine.class));
        }
        if (view.getId()==R.id.buttonback){
            onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more about this issue you facing

Comment: sure, I just added more about it

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't seem like a good idea to create an object on setOnScrollListener which gets called many many times during scrolling up/down. if you could provide more detail would be great.